# How can I split a data row into 2 rows when a condition is met?

Tags: sql

I want to classify a data row to its respective workweek based on its `equip_state_in` and `equip_state_out datetime` data. A workweek is defined as every Thursday, 7pm to the next Thursday 7pm. The workweek start and end datetime is found in the `start_date_time` and `end_date_time` columns. The workweek data is found in one data table while the equip_state datetimes are found in another data table, both of which will be joined subsequently to show the respective workweek of every data row in the equip_state_datetime table.

| work_week | start_date_time | end_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2023-03-07 19:00:00.000 | 2023-03-14 18:59:59.000 |
| 12 | 2023-03-14 19:00:00.000 | 2023-03-21 18:59:59.000 |
| 40 | 2023-09-28 19:00:00.000 | 2023-10-05 18:59:59.000 |

| equip_state_in_datetime | equip_state_out_datetime | work_week | work_week_year | start_date_time | end_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-13 23:15:10.887 | 2024-03-14 21:16:26.227 | Null | Null | Null | Null |

So for instance, if the data shows that the `equip_state_in_datetime` is 13 Mar 2024 23:15:10 and the `equip_state_out_datetime` is 14 Mar 2024 21:16:26. This single row of data should be split into 2 rows based on the workweek's definition. The desired output should show:

| equip_state_in_datetime | equip_state_out_datetime | work_week | work_week_year | start_date_time | end_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-13 23:15:10.887 | **2024-03-14 18:59:59.000** | 11 | 2024 | 2024-03-07 19:00:00.000 | 2024-03-14 18:59:59.000 |
| **2024-03-14 19:00:00.000** | 2024-03-14 21:16:26.227 | 12 | 2024 | 2024-03-14 19:00:00.000 | 2024-03-21 18:59:59.000 |

Where the 1st row should show the original `equip_state_in_datetime` and an `equip_state_out_datetime` of the workweek's `end_date_time` value. While the 2nd row should show an `equip_state_in_datetime` of the workweek's `start_date_time` value and the original `equip_state_out_datetime`.

However if the `state_in` and `state_out_datetime` falls within the workweek, then the data row would remain unchanged. For instance, if the data shows that the `equip_state_in_datetime` is 30 Sep 2023 07:47:59 and the `equip_state_out_datetime` is 30 Sep 2023 17:06:20 then the output should remain as:

| equip_state_in_datetime | equip_state_out_datetime | work_week | work_week_year | start_date_time | end_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-30 07:47:59.363 | 2023-09-30 17:06:20.493 | 40 | 2023 | 2023-09-28 19:00:00.000 | 2023-10-05 18:59:59.000 |

Essentially, the workweek's `start` and `end_date_time` should serve as the date period that the `equip_state_in` and `equip_state_out_datetime` should compare against to determine the appropriate workweek and if necessary, to split the data row into 2 rows where the `equip_state_datetime` crosses the defined workweek's range.

When the period of the `equip_state_in_datetime` and `equip_state_out_datetime` crosses between 2 workweeks, my current query will just show a NULL result as it is unable to assign 2 different workweek values to the single data row in the equip_state_datetime table.
My current output is as follow:

| equip_state_in_datetime | equip_state_out_datetime | work_week | work_week_year | start_date_time | end_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-13 23:15:10.887 | 2024-03-14 21:16:26.227 | Null | Null | Null | Null |

My current SQL script is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM equip_state_datetime 
LEFT JOIN workweek 
    ON equip_state_in_datetime >= start_date_time 
   AND equip_state_out_datetime <= end_date_time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example

```
SELECT e.equip_state_in_datetime,e.equip_state_out_datetime
  ,case when e.equip_state_in_datetime>w.start_date_time 
       then e.equip_state_in_datetime
   else w.start_date_time
   end ew_start_date_time
  ,case when e.equip_state_out_datetime<w.end_date_time 
       then e.equip_state_out_datetime
   else w.end_date_time
   end ew_end_date_time
  ,w.work_week,w.start_date_time w_start_date_time,w.end_date_time w_end_date_time
FROM equip_state_datetime e
LEFT JOIN workweek w
    ON equip_state_in_datetime between w.start_date_time  and w.end_date_time
  or equip_state_out_datetime between w.start_date_time  and w.end_date_time
  or w.start_date_time between equip_state_in_datetime and equip_state_out_datetime
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick solution! I managed to test it out and it worked like a charm! The magic in the conditional statement at the LEFT JOIN clause helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need little bit change join condition to intersects. You can doit like this:

```
equip_state_out_datetime >= start_date_time and
end_date_time >= equip_state_in_datetime
```

After you can modify thats fields in select:

```
    greatest(start_date_time, equip_state_in_datetime) as equip_state_in_datetime,
    least(end_date_time, equip_state_out_datetime) as equip_state_out_datetime,
```

Comment: What mean ``start_end_time``?

Comment: Thank you). I made a mistake when copy-pasted :) Edited.

Comment: This is more compact join condition, well.

Comment: Hi Gwaeren, is the function `GREATEST` supported on SQL? I get this error when I insert the second block of code in `SELECT`. 
'GREATEST' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Most dialects support it. But if your not support it then better use case/when.
https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/greatest-least